# my application crashes trying to call native method while woking on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, crash, android-ndk

I am developing a program that uses native code and it works fine on the testing device `Samsung galaxy S`

but when i try it on the emulator it doesn't work , the program just closes with no exceptions.

while debugging i found that the program crashes once it reaches a call to any native method

is there a way to make the program work on emulator?

Edit: i tried another program that uses native methods on emulator and it worked.

Comment: What error do you get? What does logcat say?

Comment: i get no error , the program just closes
;
logcat behaves normally and its output is the same as the device , until it reaches the call to native method and it closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application works with native ARM code also on emulator. The emulator behaves as normal ARM device, and emulates also ARM code.

I have no problems running my native apps on the emulator.

You should study logcat output to find reason of your failures.

Comment: logcat behaves normally and its output is the same as the device , until it reaches the call to native method and it closes

Comment: Try to run some other app with native code in your emulator. Maybe it's somehow corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call LoadLibrary? The NDK includes example programs like HelloJNI. You should be able to get that to run, then work from there.

Comment: i did call that , and the logcat indicates that the library has been loaded